# Single tap does not seelct row in uitableview ios 7

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, ios7

I have `UITableView` in my app. In that table, cells have labels. But in `iOS 7` when I tap on the row it does not select the row. But if I tap on row using two fingers it works fine. It works fine on `iOS 5.0` and `6.0`.

**I don't use any gesture recognizer**.

What would be the reason for that and anyone having any idea to fix this.

My delegate methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
    *)indexPath 
    {

        NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RowIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [cell.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        width = tableView.frame.size.width;
        [self createRow:cell :indexPath]; // This will add label to the content view
        if (![self isSelectable:indexPath.row]) 
        {
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO; 
        } else 
        {
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }

        for (id obj in cell.subviews)
        {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([obj class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"])
            {
                UIScrollView *scroll = (UIScrollView *) obj;
                scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
                break;
            }
        }
        [cell setExclusiveTouch:YES];
        UIView * selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.000 green:0.000 blue:1.000 alpha:1.000]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Show your tableview delegate and datasorce methods.

Comment: Yes, show your methods.

Comment: did you add any gesture recogniser in your view

Comment: Adding my voice to this, I have the same bug as OP. If you've figured this out, could you let me know?

Comment: I am also having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any gesture recognizer in your view, like a TapRecognizer, this might prevent the gesture to reach your table cell, the solution for this is to set your gesture recognizer as:

[gestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];

Comment: This should be selected as the correct answer. Deserves more up votes